# mapping error react.js (TypeError: this.props.historyAtLocation.map is not a function)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping, redux, reducers

I'm trying to perform map on the array of objects in react, but receive an error 
`TypeError: this.props.historyAtLocation.map is not a function. (In 'this.props.historyAtLocation.map(this.renderWeather)', 'this.props.historyAtLocation.map' is undefined)`

Though, if I make `console.log('test_output: ', this.props.historyAtLocation)` result is the following:

```
test_output: 
  Array (24)
    {time: 1476469800, summary: "Partly Cloudy", icon: "partly-cloudy-night", precipIntensity: 0, precipProbability: 0, …}
    {time: 1476473400, summary: "Clear", icon: "clear-night", precipIntensity: 0, precipProbability: 0, …}
    {time: 1476477000, summary: "Clear", icon: "clear-night", precipIntensity: 0, precipProbability: 0, …}
    ...
```

So you can see that is is defined, and it is an array of objects.

I was trying `map` like this:

```
this.props.historyAtLocation.map(this.renderWeather)
```

I know that this question was raised a bunch of times already, but none of the solutions works for me.

Just in case it might be useful, here is my related reducer

```
function historyAtLocation(state = { }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVED_FORECAST:
    {console.log('sample data: ', action.forecast.hourly.data)}
    return action.forecast.hourly.data
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

I think there might be some problem with the objects which are inside the array?

Any ideas appreciated, thanks

**UPD 27.10.16**
If I run

```
const hal = this.props.historyAtLocation; 
console.log(Array.isArray(hal), hal, typeof hal, hal.map, typeof hal.map)
```

as it was suggested by @biphobe, I receive following output:

[image]

Comment: Please format your code properly, i.e. indent it, including the error you showed at the start. Otherwise its very hard to read.

Comment: @AndreasWolf Thanks for a feedback, done

Comment: @Olenka Run the below checks and copy here the logs/screenshot please:

const hal = this.props.historyAtLocation;
console.log(Array.isArray(hal), hal, typeof hal, hal.map, typeof hal.map)

Comment: @biphobe thanks a lot for your suggestion! I've attached screenshot of the output. Please, let me know if you have any other ideas to check, to what to do with the result

Comment: @Olenka This whole thing is odd, I don't think I can help you without working demo of your code.